# Performance - extending C++ with Python function

Tags: python, c++, embed

I have a main application written in C++. To give user some more dynamic control via scripting, I chose to embed some python in the code. FYI, my user are not keen on learning and writing any C++, so shared lib is out of the question. The C++ code will call user defined function in python at runtime.

Ex: user would write the following python function. Of cause, in practice user would supply a bit more complex function definition than a simple add.

```
def userAdd(a, b):
    return a+b
```

The C++ code uses the following function to call userAdd. I need to run evalUserFunc many times with various sets of (a,b). How slow would this method be compared to calling a hard coded C++ function. I'm seeing a .pyc generated upon execution. Is this some what analogues to a .so in C++? Thank you in advance.

```
float myClass::evalUserFunc(float a, float b)
{
    PyObject *pFunc, *pArgs;
    PyObject *pa, *pb, *pValue;
    int res = 0;
    if (_pModule != NULL) {
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(_pModule, 'userAdd');
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(2);
        pa = PyFloat_FromDouble(a);
        pb = PyFloat_FromDouble(b);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pa);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 1, pb);
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);
        res = PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: The performance impact is enough to encourage not crossing the Native <-> Scripting boundry often.

Comment: It's really dangerous to execute user-written code, not only because it might break your program, but also because an experienced and malicious user can cause some real damage. I would suggest finding some other way around your problem or removing the feature altogether.

Comment: What are other alternatives?